# zsh completion inside quoted strings

Tags: quotes, zsh, tab-completion

Is it possible to configure zsh to suggest filenames (or anything else) inside of a quoted string?

I've seen this thread on bash: [Bash TAB-completion inside double-quoted string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731219/bash-tab-completion-inside-double-quoted-string)
But I'm not sure whether that solution is compatible between shells.

Answer (score 1):

No problem for tab completion inside quotes.

```
$ touch "spaces in a filename"
$ ls
spaces in a filename
$ ls sp[TAB]
gives ->
$ ls spaces\ in\ a\ filename

$ ls "sp[TAB]
gives ->
$ ls "spaces in a filename"
```

Comment: But it only works if the filename is at the beginning of the string. 
`touch foo` 
`git add foo` 
`git commit 'Add f<TAB>` 
`No matches for: 'changed in index file' or 'changed in working tree file'`

Comment: That's because you're trying to complete a file name that starts with `Add f`, which apparently does not match to any files that were changed in your index or working tree.